# Was my question on 'entropy' deleted?

Tags: discussion

IIRC, I asked about the etymology of 'entropy': was it deleted?

Answer (score 4):

I checked your question history, including deleted questions, and I can't find anything that looks like the one you're talking about. So, the way it looks is, no, the question was never deleted because you never asked it in the first place. (At least not using this account)

A question about the etymology of a term probably wouldn't be on topic here anyway.